# How to immediately notify the Akka WebSocket server that the WebSocket client has stopped

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am using Akka WebSockets for client-server communication.

### On the client:

```
source
    .viaMat(Http().webSocketClientFlow(httpReq, settings))(Keep.both)
    .toMat(sink)(Keep.both)
    .run()
```

where **source** is

```
val source = Source.actorRef[Object](Int.MaxValue,OverflowStrategy.fail)
```

And the sink forwards all the messages to `ClientActor`.

### On the server:

```
val requestHandler: HttpRequest => HttpResponse = {
      case req @ HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/"), _, _, _) =>
        req.header[UpgradeToWebSocket] match {
          case Some(upgrade: UpgradeToWebSocket) =>

            /**
              * Create an ActorRef for the client. Sending messages to this actor replies to the client.
              * fanout = false, because there is only one output (no broadcasting).
              */
            val source: Source[Object, ActorRef] = Source.actorRef[Object](Int.MaxValue, OverflowStrategy.fail)

            val (clientActor: ActorRef, publisher) = source
              .via(flow)
              .toMat(Sink.asPublisher(fanout = false))(Keep.both).run()

            // receives messages from the client

            val sink: Sink[Message, NotUsed] = Common.getSink(messageHandler, clientActor)

            upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(sink, Source.fromPublisher(publisher))

          case None =>
            HttpResponse(400, entity = "Not a valid websocket request!")
        }
      case r: HttpRequest =>
        r.discardEntityBytes() // important to drain incoming HTTP Entity stream
        HttpResponse(404, entity = "Unknown resource!")
    }
```

And the `sink` forwards all the messages to the `ServerActor`.

### ServerActor

```
def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case Terminated(sender) =>
      logger.info(s"Detected that client disconnected: $sender")
```

But when I stop the clientActor with `clientActor ! PoisonPill` the server takes exactly a minutes to detect that the clientActor has been disconnected. What changes do I need to make in the clientActor or the serverActor to detect the disconnect immideately? Any pointers will be appriciated.

### Debugging I've done:

I have tried using `system.context.terminate()` and with this the ServerActor immidiately detects the disconnect, but then it does not allow me to create a new ClientActor. I run into "[Why does Akka fail with "IllegalStateException: cannot create children while terminating or terminated" when testing with ScalaTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130391/why-does-akka-fail-with-illegalstateexception-cannot-create-children-while-ter)" error.

I did a little digging around and found that the Akka WebSocket uses `streamSupervisor` actors for communication and both the `clientActor` and `serverActor` watches these `streamSupervisor` actors.

Expectation here is to immideately detect the client disconnection on the `serverActor` actor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Sink.actorRef` for the sink of the flow. After the connection is terminated by the client, the actor will receive this message and you can poison the child actor which corresponding to the WebSocket.